# How can I stream an m4v url from Google Cloud Platform using Exoplayer

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, exoplayer2.x

I want to use Exoplayer to stream an m4v video URL link https://storage.cloud.google.com/math_oneticha/Numbers/NUMBERS.m4v?authuser=2 from google cloud storage, but my app keeps crashing because no available Exoplayer extractor can read the stream. When I use the same URL link on a browser, it streams perfectly. I also tried streaming a mp4 URL, `https://media.publit.io/file/Mathematic/LinearEquation/Linear-Equation-4.mp4`with the  exoplayer app and it streams perfectly meaning the exoplayer app is simply just having a challenges with the m4v url. Below is my code for the exoplayer

```
 Uri videoUrl;
// Initialize Player view and variables
 PlayerView player;
ProgressBar vprogressBar;
ImageView fullScreenImage, closeLecture;
SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;

// ref Player variables
    player = findViewById(R.id.playerView);
    vprogressBar = findViewById(R.id.video_loading_bar);
    fullScreenImage = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_option);
    closeLecture = findViewById(R.id.videoClose);

    String stringUrl = "https://storage.cloud.google.com/math_oneticha/Numbers/NUMBERS.m4v?authuser=2";
    videoUrl = Uri.parse(stringUrl);
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
    );

    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(LectureActivity.this, trackSelector,loadControl);
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer video");
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUrl,factory,extractorsFactory,null,null);
    player.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
    player.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener(){
        
         @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING){
                vprogressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY){
                vprogressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    }
```

And below is my crash log

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
```

Please what can I do differently so my app can stream my m4v url link from google cloud storage?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you need to use `gsutil cp` for a streaming transfers into ExoPlayer.
I don't know much about the whole process but I found the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) that may send you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't understand anything written in the referred document. Besides, I just discover the exoplayer code works well with some of google cloud URL and throws Error for others. I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: Need more details to going further, which kind of error do you see while trying? Maybe a permission issue, API to enable, etc   

Please share more details

Comment: Thanks, @Bruno, but I have sorted it out. Apparently, the Exoplayer was working fine, just had some issues with some of my cloud storage links.